# Как вывести ячейки fpdf в цикле?

Tags: php, pdo, fpdf

Прошу помочь с библиотекой FPDF.

**Проблема:** не получается вывести в цикле ячейки `$pdf->Cell` в документ PDF
В БД данные присутствуют, из базы выбираю следующим запросом

```
// запросы в бд
$gsign = "ГЖД";
$sqlg = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE sign = ?";
$gquery = $dbh->prepare($sqlg);
$gquery->execute([$gsign]);
$resultg = $gquery->fetchALL();
```

Затем циклом **планировал** выводить всё в колонку друг за дружкой

```
foreach ($resultg as $k => $v) {
    $pdf->Cell(0, 4, " " . $v['title'], 1, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->ln();
}
```

Но код выше ничего не генерирует на странице FPDF, к сожалению.

Запрос в базу и тот же самый код отдельно от библиотеки выбирает и отображает на странице все необходимые мне данные.

```
require_once("databaseconnection.php");

// запросы в бд
$gsign = "ГЖД";
$sqlg = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE sign = ?";
$gquery = $dbh->prepare($sqlg);
$gquery->execute([$gsign]);
$resultg = $gquery->fetchALL();

echo "<br />";
foreach ($resultg as $k => $v) {
    echo $v['title'] . "<br />";
}
```

Я грешу на особенности работы с fpdf, но никак не могу разобраться. В интернете ячейки fpdf, по примерам, генерируют в точно таком же виде (вот пример из мануала на одном из сайтов)

```
for ( $i=0; $i < count( $rowLabels ); $i++ ) {
  $pdf->SetXY( $chartXPos + 40 +  $i / $xScale, $chartYPos );
  $pdf->Cell( $barWidth, 10, $rowLabels[$i], 0, 0, 'C' );
}
```

Я пробовал заменить цикл в следующий вид

```
foreach ($resultg as $k => $v) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($v); $i++) {
        $pdf->Cell(0, 4, " " . $v['title'], 1, 1, 'C');
        $pdf->ln();
    }
}
```

но и это безрезультатно. Прошу Вашего содействия.

Comment: ап! господа, ну никак без Вашей помощи) уже всё, до чего додумался, испробовал(